# UITableView puts cell content on wrong rows after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

Although there are couple of posts in the site regarding UITableview cell repetition when scrolled, I could nt find the solution, perhaps because am pretty new to obj-c.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];

    UILabel *firstlabel   = nil;
    UILabel *secondlabel  = nil;
    UILabel *thirdlabel   = nil;

    myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
   if(!cell) {
        cell = [[myTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
   }

  if (noOfRows < [_eachrow count]-1) {

    _eachcolumn = [_eachrow[noOfRows] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    firstlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 142.0,tableView.rowHeight)];
    firstlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    firstlabel.text = _eachcolumn[0];
    firstlabel.textAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;
    firstlabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:firstlabel];

    secondlabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(142.0, 0, 50.0,tableView.rowHeight)];
    secondlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    secondlabel.text = _eachcolumn[1];
    secondlabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secondlabel];

    thirdlabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(192.0, 0, 60.0,tableView.rowHeight)];
    thirdlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    thirdlabel.text = _eachcolumn[2];
    thirdlabel.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
    thirdlabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:thirdlabel];

    noOfRows++;
    return cell;
  }
   else return cell;

}
```

So, my problem is when I scroll up or down, the cells keep placed at wrong rows without a pattern. Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're adding your labels in code like this. You have a custom cell (myTableViewCell), why not set up the labels in IB (if you're using that), or in the init method for the cell? Also, the cell identifier should be a constant, not different for every row.

Comment: the number of rows are unknown(they might vary for every dates)..they are dynamic cells..i am creating them programatically..essentially, my app pulls up data from a php and displays in a uitableview for the date selected. I knew not a better way to do this.
This is working fine except that when I scroll, the rows scramble pretty much :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem occurs because the cells are reusable and you need to override the values each time in `cellForRow` .

Try this instead:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];



    myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   if(!cell) {
        cell = [[myTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UILabel *firstlabel   = nil;
    UILabel *secondlabel  = nil;
    UILabel *thirdlabel   = nil;
    _eachcolumn = [_eachrow[noOfRows] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    firstlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 142.0,tableView.rowHeight)];
    firstlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    firstlabel.text = _eachcolumn[0];
    firstlabel.textAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;
    firstlabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    firstlabel.tag = 10;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:firstlabel];

    secondlabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(142.0, 0, 50.0,tableView.rowHeight)];
    secondlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    secondlabel.text = _eachcolumn[1];
    secondlabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    secondlabel.tag = 20;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secondlabel];

    thirdlabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(192.0, 0, 60.0,tableView.rowHeight)];
    thirdlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    thirdlabel.text = _eachcolumn[2];
    thirdlabel.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
    thirdlabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    thirdlabel.tag = 30;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:thirdlabel];


    return cell;
  }
   else
  {

  ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10]).text = _eachcolumn[1];
  ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20]).text = _eachcolumn[2];
  ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:30]).text = _eachcolumn[3];

  return cell;
  }
```

}

Comment: thanks for the reply @soryngod..but i still wasnt able to fix it..when I use your code, I am getting blank rows when I scroll and if I modify reuse identifier to indexPath.row from nil, the last row is repeating when I scroll..any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: hey @soryngod..i have tried this..still the problem persists..what could be wrong? I really dont understand..help please..

Comment: the problem now is that the last row is being placed in all the rows after i scroll

Comment: hey its working!! looks like i did some silly mistake somewhere before!! Thanks a lot man!! you totally saved me!! @soryngod :)